# Close off-canvas mobile menu when link is clicked (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation, off-canvas-menu

I have a mobile menu that has some anchored links that scroll to a certain section of the page when clicked. The problem with this is when I click one of these links, due to the fact that a new page is not loading, the menu remains open.

I wish to implement a solution whereby if one of these links are clicked, the menu closes by default. I have tried to hide the menu on click using JS but I think my logic may be wrong. Any help would be great.

Here is the code for my menu.

```
<div id="my-id" class="uk-offcanvas custom_canvas">
   <div class="uk-offcanvas-bar">
      <div class="uk-panel">
         <a class="btn btn primary remove_image-div" onclick="UIkit.offcanvas.hide([force = false]);"> 
            <img src="img/remove_icon.png" class="remove_image" alt="remove">
         </a>
         <ul class="mm-list mm-panel mm-opened mm-subopened" id="mm-0">
            <li class="offcanvas_li">
               <a class="offcanvas_open" title="Samples" href="index.html#sample-section">Samples</a>
            </li>
            <li class="offcanvas_li">
               <a href="index.html#package-section" title="Packages" class="offcanvas_open">Packages</a>
            </li>
            <li class="offcanvas_li">
               <a href="#about-section" title="About" class="offcanvas_open">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="offcanvas_li">
               <a href="contact.html" title="Contact" class="offcanvas_open">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="offcanvas_li">
               <a href="blog.html" title="Blog" class="offcanvas_open">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="offcanvas_li">
               <a class="offcanvas_open" title="We Love" href="we_love.html">We Love</a>
           </li> 
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `UIkit.offcanvas` plugin but with a little sense I can answer you that you can add them (the links) all the attribute `onclick="UIkit.offcanvas.hide([force = false]);"`

A **better** (generic) solution is to "listen" to their `click` event, then, run offcanvas command.

Something like:

```
$('.offcanvas_li a').click(function() {
   UIkit.offcanvas.hide([force = false]);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this reply. I just tried this and it doesnt seem to work. I tried something similar earlier but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? Can you create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) ot [bin](http://jsbin.com/?html,js,output)? Or even better, do you have a public URL so I could try to debug it?

Comment: Hi Mosh. I found a JS file that was using an id to trigger the effect. I duplicated this code and added your suggestion in the head and it seems to have worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! Some adjustments from my context: `$('.uk-offcanvas a').click(() => { window.UIkit.offcanvas.hide() })`

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
    <script>
  function myFunction() {
  UIkit.offcanvas.hide([force = false])
  }</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Close Panel</button>
```